# Rank of Jacobian is constant

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

We recall that the rank of a mapping $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ of a domain $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $x\in U$ is the rank of the linear transformation tangent to it at the point, that is, the rank of the matrix $f'(x)$. The rank of a mapping at a point is usually denoted $\text{rank} f(x)$.

Assume that we have the following statement.

> Let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a mapping defined in a neighborhood
> $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ of a point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^m$. Assume that
> $f\in C^{1}(U;\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the mapping $f$ has the same rank $k$
> at every point $x\in U$.

So we know that for any $x\in U$ we have a linear transformation $f'(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and the matrix of this transformation is the following $n\times m$ matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(x) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_m}(x) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}(x) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_m}(x)
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Also we know that for any $x\in U$ the rank of this matrix is $k$.
However, the rest reasoning sounds a bit weird.

> In order to avoid relabeling the coordinates and the neighborhood $U$,
> we shall assume that at every point $x\in U$, the principal minor of
> order $k$ in the upper left corner of the matrix $f'(x)$ is nonzero.

Obviously they are using the following definition definition of rank of matrix which is the size of largest nonzero minor. If we fix $x_1\in U$, then we know that $\text{rank}f'(x_1)=k$ and we have some nonzero minor and WLOG we can assume that it is the upper left corner of $f'(x_1)$. However, for $x_2\neq x_1$ it could be a different minor and  we cannot say in general that it is also upper left minor. So my point is that the position of minor also depends on $x\in U$.

I hope that my question is formulated in a clear way. If not, then please let me know.
I am wondering can anyone explain this please? This is so unclear.

**Addendum.** I am going to do exactly what @SeverinSchraven did but for some concrete values of $n$ and $m$. Consider the particular case when $n=3$ and $m=5$. In that case we functions $f_1,f_2,f_3:U\to \mathbb{R}$, where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^5$. Also we know that $\text{rank} (\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j})=3$, where the matrix has $3$ rows and $5$ columns. WLOG assume that for all $x\in U$, we have $$\det\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_2 f_1 & \partial_3 f_1 & \partial_5 f_1 \\
\partial_2 f_2 & \partial_3 f_2 & \partial_5 f_2 \\
\partial_2 f_3 & \partial_3 f_3 & \partial_5 f_3 
\end{pmatrix}\neq 0.$$ It means that here $\ell_1=2, \ell_2=3, \ell_3=5$.
Hence $Q:=[5]\setminus \{2,3,5\}=\{1,4\}$ and $\varphi:\{1,4\}\to \{4,5\}$ be a bijection defined as $\varphi(1)=4$ and $\varphi(4)=5$. Then $\Phi:[5]\to [5]$ defined as
$$\Phi(i) =
\begin{cases}
\ell_i, & \text{if }i\in [3] \\
1, & \text{if }i=4 \\
4, & \text{if }5=4
\end{cases}.$$
Then you consider the mapping $A:\mathbb{R}^5\to \mathbb{R}^5$ defined as $A(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(x_{\Phi(1)},x_{\Phi(2)},x_{\Phi(3)},x_{\Phi(4)},x_{\Phi(5)})=(x_2,x_3,x_5,x_1,x_4).$ Then it is not difficult to check that $A(1,0,0,0,0)=(0,0,0,1,0)$, i.e. $Ae_1=e_4=e_{\Phi^{-1}(1)}$. But in **@SeverinSchraven's last comment** he said that he defined $A$ in such a way that $Ae_1=e_{\Phi(1)}$ which does not hold in that setting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the fact that the determinant is continuous in the entries and $\partial_j f_i(x)$ are continuous in $x$. Hence, if a minor is positive at some $x_0$, then it is positive in a full nbhd of $x_0$. Thus, if we restrict to this smaller nbhd, we may assume that we can fix the minor that is positive (and after relabelling the coordinates, we can assume that it is prinicipal minor of order $k$  in the upper left corner of the matrix $f'(x)$).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144704/discussion-on-answer-by-severin-schraven-rank-of-jacobian-is-constant); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.